# syntax error dont know if redshift or sql

Tags: sql, postgresql, amazon-redshift

There seems to be error with the syntax. I am getting this error

```
ERROR: syntax error at or near "update"
  Position: 188

update t
^

Execution time: 0.11s
```

Can someone please help. I dont know if it is a sql or just a redshift error (I am new to sql and redshift both)

```sql
With tbl  as
(
Select Count(1) as cnt, b.ucn 
FROM 
storiacloud.schl_storia_school_status_try b
INNER JOIN 
storiacloud.vw_storia_oms_orders a ON a.school_ucn = b.ucn 
Group By b.ucn 
) 
update t
SET no_of_orders = tbl.Cnt 
From  tbl
join storiacloud.schl_storia_school_status_try as t on t.ucn = tbl.ucn
```

Comment: Would be useful if you provide a complete test case, including DDL of your tables. Make it a minimal non-working example (as in: exclude columns from tables which do not appear in your queries). Also please specify if you tried the query on a vanilla PostgreSQL, and which version did you try.

Comment: Fixed some typos and grammar

Answer (score 2):

Redshift doesn't support WITH ... UPDATE.

Redshift is a derivative of PostgreSQL, but it was forked at PostgreSQL version 8.0.2.  The WITH ... UPDATE statement wasn't added to PostgreSQL until 9.1.

See:

[Redshift UPDATE](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/r_UPDATE.html)

[PostgreSQL 8.0 UPDATE](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.0/static/sql-update.html)

[PostgreSQL 9.1 UPDATE](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/sql-update.html)